# Read javascript value in a page then post it back using http protocol

Tags: delphi, http, indy

I have a PHP page that has many javascript variables and I want to read a specific javascript variable then post this value using HTTP post.

I know how to post the value using Indy but I don't know how to read JS variable. Please advise what tool I should use, any code snippet would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean the javascript variable as a string (name of the variable), or do you mean the actual value?

Comment: When you already know the HTTP part, then your question is not related to Indy or HTTP, thus you should not use those tags for your question.

Comment: About your problem, you can use a RegEx engine to find and extract JavaScript codes from a given text. What version of Delphi are you using? Can you add a sample of the text here?

Answer (score 0):

Unless the JS variable is assigned a static value in its code (in which case, just grep the JS code for what you need), then you will have to actually execute the JS code using a real JS scripting engine, just like a webbrowser would.